# "Warning: func_get_arg(): Argument ... not passed to function in ..."

Tags: php, parameters, variadic-functions

Why does the following code produce "Warning: func_get_arg():  Argument 1 not passed to function in /t.php(6) : assert code on line 1"?

```
function func($param0/*, ...*/)
{
    assert('is_string(func_get_arg(0))'); // ok
    assert('is_string(func_get_arg(1))'); // error
}
func("param0", "param1");
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/5G9kMWKJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be because the `func_get_arg` is referring to the `assert` call, NOT to the `func`.

Demo of it working with `var_dump`: http://codepad.org/37uDiSDy

Comment: An imperfection of PHP or by design?

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing as the `arguments` magic variable in JavaScript. If you enter an anonymous function (or an `eval` context) then its value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [insightful comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php#78176) on PHP's page for assert:

> Note that func_get_args() should be used carefully [in assert] and never in a string! ... This is because of that the string passed to assert() is being evaled inside assert, and not your function.